# Unable to use PostFile to upload image

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to use PostFile to upload an image. As a simple example I have the following DTO:

```
[Route("/Pictures/{Id}", "GET, PUT, DELETE")]
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class PictureResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region Implementation of IHasResponseStatus

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

My GET works fine:

```
public override object OnGet(Picture request)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PictureRepository.Get(request.Id).Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    return new HttpResult(memoryStream, "image/png");
}
```

But my PostFile blows up:

```
var imagePathInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\avatars\symang.jpg");
var serviceClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:52712/api")
serviceClient.PostFile<PictureResponse>("/Pictures/{0}".Fmt(id), imagePathInfo, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(imagePathInfo.Name));
```

Here's the error and stack trace:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error: 


Line 32:             var imagePathInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Mark\Downloads\avatars\symang.jpg");
Line 33:             var serviceClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:52712/api");
Line 34:             serviceClient.PostFile<PictureResponse>("/Pictures/{0}".Fmt(id), imagePathInfo, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(imagePathInfo.Name));
Line 35:             RedirectToAction("Index");
Line 36:             return View();

Source File: C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sandbox\UploadFileAttachments\UploadFileAttachments\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 34 

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +6210712
System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +134

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +318
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.MakeMemoryStream(Stream stream) +221

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.]
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6115603
ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.PostFile(String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Stream fileToUpload, String fileName, String mimeType) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\ServiceClient.Web\ServiceClientBase.cs:815
ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.PostFile(String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, FileInfo fileToUpload, String mimeType) in C:\src\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\ServiceClient.Web\ServiceClientBase.cs:790
UploadFileAttachments.Controllers.HomeController.ChangePicture(Int32 id) in C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sandbox\UploadFileAttachments\UploadFileAttachments\Controllers\HomeController.cs:34
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +150
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

I'm sure I must be misunderstanding how to use PostFile. By the way, I never hit my OnPost method on my service. Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

`PostFile` does a HTTP `POST`.
But your service only allows `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` because of your route in the first line of your example code:

```
[Route("/Pictures/{Id}", "GET, PUT, DELETE")]
```

**Solution:**

Either include `POST` in your route:

```
[Route("/Pictures/{Id}", "GET, PUT, DELETE, POST")]
```

...or just omit the HTTP verbs:

```
[Route("/Pictures/{Id}")]
```